# Showing different calendars in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, calendar

I'm trying to get a complete list of all calendars. If I list

```
(new Appointments()).Accounts
```

I get only accounts like "Windows Live" or "Google". Actually I need a way to get the calendars and the appointments to that calendar inside the accounts. But it has to be on any account, not only the Live Account. Read only access is enough though. Is there any possibility?

If there is no chance, is this possible under WP8? Yes, I know, hardware capabilities were to high for this feature under WP7.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method [`Appointments.SearchAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh220723%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which you should use. There is quite a nice example on MSDN:

```
        Appointments appts = new Appointments();

        appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<AppointmentsSearchEventArgs>(Appointments_SearchCompleted);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = start.AddDays(7);

        appts.SearchAsync(start, end, "Appointments Test #1");
```

Within callback function you'll have access to `args.Results` of type `IEnumerable<Appointment>`.

This is available on both WP7.1 and WP8.

Comment: Probably you understood me wrong. I've done this already, but for example I have two account (Windows Live and Google) and there I have each two Calendars (maybe Private and Work). So I want to get only Appointments, that are saved in Google-Work Calendar. With this method I get all appointments. I could filter by Google, but I need only Work from Google. Hopefully you know what I mean ;)

Comment: So I assume there is no way you can achieve that. You can only filter by Calendar (there is another overload with additional parameter for that).

Comment: Which actually means, I can only filter by account. Thank you anyway!